# setTextColor and setColorFilter not the same color in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. They both use `?attr/somecolor` to see what color they have to use depending on what theme is selected. This `somecolor` is either black or white depending on theme.

Now when I say they both need to be red using `R.color.red`, the TextView has a more brighter red then the ImageView.

```
sometext.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.green))
someimage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green))
```

Is there any reason why these colors don't match up?

[image]

Comment: Try setting mode in the color filter of an image view, which is 2nd argument in the setColorFilter method. Like this 

imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

Comment: tried this, doesn't seem to do much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's what I get for an `ImageView` with `app:tint="@color/black` and a `TextView` with `android:textColor="@colorBlack`, and then

```
someText.setTextColor(Color.RED)
someImage.setColorFilter(Color.RED)
```

[image: The result with both elements tinted the same colour]

It's hard to say exactly what you need to do, but there are two different things going on here. For the `TextView`, you're literally just telling it what colour to draw with. That should always come out looking how you expect.

But for images, it's a little more complicated. You're applying a *tint* over existing image data, which interacts with the original colours **and alpha** to produce a final mixed image. For a bitmap image, that colour is in the individual pixels. For a vector drawable, it's in attributes like the `fillColor`.

For example, that fill colour on the arrow is `@color/white`, but here's what happens if I knock the alpha down by setting `android:fillColor="#AAFFFFFF"`:

[image: The full red applied over a vector drawable with less than full alpha]

You can see the colour is different - it's actually partially transparent so it's blending with the white background. Applying full-alpha red over it didn't change the overall alpha - and it can't really, it's the alpha that says which parts of that square image are "empty" and which are "the arrow". (Well, you *can* do that with a different PorterDuff mode, but by default it doesn't!)

---

The alpha of your tint matters too - here's a partially transparent tint applied to the `@color/white` arrow (and the text):

```
someText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#99FF0000"))
someImage.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#99FF0000"))
```

[image: Tint applied to white arrow - it's pale red]

And here's the same tint applied when the arrow's fill colour is `@color/black`

[image: Tint applied to black arrow - it's noticeably darker]

So the colour tint, when it's partially transparent, only really *shifts* the overall colour appearance, rather than fully replacing it. So check your `R.color.green` value and make sure it's actually fully opaque. If it's not, and that's how you want it, then pay attention to the `fillColor` you're using - you can see there that I'm applying the exact same colour to the text, but it matches more closely when the arrow is white

---

The other thing is the different `PorterDuff` tinting modes you can apply with `setColorFilter` - I can't really go into them right now (some info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode) and [here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/practical-image-porterduff-mode-usage-in-android-3b4b5d2e8f5f)) but you can control how the *tint colour* and the *image* are composited, how they're blended together.

Ideally you'd just make your image's `fillColor` white and apply your tint to it and call it a day, but if you can't do that (because it's in use elsewhere) or you need to tint bitmaps, you can look into that stuff!

Comment: Thanks for your super nice explanation, when I checked the xml file from the Image I was using I saw that the android:alpha was set to 0.8 now when I set it to 1, the colors are now the same!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `?astr` which is for the main portion of the app user interface example navbar and things like that. You can create your color as Third Primary Color and just call it from there. I only use the `?astr` for main color of the title bar or nav bar.

When you define the color as a third primary define the same color in both themes. You should get the same color for both. I do this a lot on all of my apps.

Also Android Studio is yelling at me saying that the `?astr` is no longer needed. So I have a feeling that it will be done away with in the future.

Also defining your own colors will ensure the colors are the same. Be sure to set the same `#13345fg`(not actual color) with both themes that are pre-built for the app.